# nothing is working except 'not empty' validation in cakephp

Tags: validation, cakephp

I'm new to CakePHP. I'm validating my form, but the problem is that no validation is working except the not empty validation.

My model file is:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';
    public $validate = array(
        'rule_name' => array(
            'alphaNumeric' => array(
                'rule' => 'Numeric',
                'required' => true, 
                'message' => 'Letters and numbers only' 
            )
        )
    );
}
```

My View file is:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('rule_name',array('class'=>'form-control','autocomplete'=>'off'));
```

Please suggest how I can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

General usage pattern adding a rule for a single field:

```
public $validate = array(
    'fieldName1' => array(
        'rule' => 'ruleName',
        'required' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => 'Your Error Message'
    )
);
```

Must be look at [Data Validation in cakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#one-rule-per-field)